# How to Skip duplicate Lines in Google Sheet w. If/Else Statement to Deliver Unique Values in HTML UI Table?

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Sheets, I have a list of several Purchase Order Numbers that have accumulated through time in column A of my 'POHistory' tab (see example in code area below).  Right now, the script is successfully posting order numbers to my HTML UI table, but I am stuck, though, in determining how to have the if/else statement shown in the APPS Script code below grab & post only unique order number values to the HTML UI.  Right now, the code is posting all 5 entries shown below.  It should, though, post only the 2 unique values.

```
Example from POHistory Tab:
COLUMN A
SAMPLE PO
SAMPLE PO 
SAMPLE PO
SAMPLE PO II
SAMPLE PO II

APPS SCRIPT:
function htmlOrders() {
   var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sheet = active.getSheetByName("POHistory");
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:K" + lastRow); 
   var data = myRange.getValues();
   var optionsHTML = " ";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
 if(data[i][0] == data[i++][0]){
  continue;
  }else{
   optionsHTML += "<tr>";
   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){   
    optionsHTML += "<td>" + "<input type=radio name=selectedPO value=data[i][0] onclick=radio();>" +"</td>";
    optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][0] + "</td>";
    optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][2] + "</td>";
    optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][1] + "</td>";
    optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][10] + "</td>";
    optionsHTML += "</tr>"};
   return optionsHTML;
}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  if(data[i][0] == data[i++][0]){
     continue;
  }else{
     optionsHTML += "<tr>";
     // Do we need to go through rows again looks like you 
     //  only need the current row i and its 0,2,1,10 columns...
     for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){   
        optionsHTML += "<td>" + "<input type=radio name=selectedPO value=data[i][0] onclick=radio();>" +"</td>";
        optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][0] + "</td>";
        optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][2] + "</td>";
        optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][1] + "</td>";
        optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][10] + "</td>";
        optionsHTML += "</tr>"
     }
   // you also only go through the first loop once and then
   // after the second for loop(everything) return everything. 
   return optionsHTML;
}
```

Why are we looping through data twice?

Why not create a map that tells us if we have processed that type. This way the column doesn't *need* to be sorted.

```
var optionsHTML = "";
var seenType = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   if(seenType[data[i][0]){
      continue;
   }
   seenType[data[i][0]] = true;
   optionsHTML += "<tr>";
   optionsHTML += "<td>" + "<input type=radio name=selectedPO value=data[i][0] onclick=radio();>" +"</td>";
   optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][0] + "</td>";
   optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][2] + "</td>";
   optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][1] + "</td>";
   optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][10] + "</td>";
   optionsHTML += "</tr>"
}
// return outside of the for loop!!
return optionsHTML;
```

Comment: Works beautifully.  Thank you!